# Xcode Memory Graph Debugging Icon not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, memory

I've recently started working on an existing objc project and wanted to check the memory graph debugging tool. As I started a debugger with the app I realised it doesn't show in the debugging tools.

I tried it with another project (created a new swift project) and the icon suddenly did show again. But only for this project.

So my question now is if there're any settings in a particular project that can prevent the memory graph debugging tool from showing?

Any hints are appreciated. 
I tried a lot of different simulators (iOS 9/10/11). I event tried rebooting my macbook because I read somewhere this could help ;-)

I'm using an objc only project with Xcode 9.1 or Xcode 9.2 beta 2.

This is my diagnostics selection in the scheme if that's related:

[image: diagnostic selection]

Comment: Same question...

Comment: I haven't checked in a while and now (sadly I don't know what else changed) I'm able to select this option in my project like it never even was gone... But it seems to be a problem to others as well, so I'll leave this open?

Comment: Same situation now...

Comment: I have this problem as well. Only on device, not on simulator. I'm working together on this project, my partner doesn't have this issue on his iPhone 7 (I have it on my iPhone X)

Comment: Wow, even with the same project @Menno . This feels really random to me and I’m obviously not alone with this. Do the iPhone 7 and X run the same iOS version?

Comment: Yes, they do. Both 7 and X run iOS 11.2

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: shut down and restart your iPhone.
Step 2: quit and reopen Xcode.

This should make the button reappear.

Comment: Not for me. Like written in the question, it’s somehow dependent on the project. Also I’m doing everything on the simulator...

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the button is not there when I test on the device, but it's there when I test on the simulator.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: @Jason I just ended up testing on the simulator. Which sucks if you want to test some features that are not available on the simulator :/

Comment: I'm just asking about the simulator. Right now I wasn't testing on a device. Still haven't resolved this one...

Answer (score 2):

Hi I was having the same issue. It's actually hidden here:

[image]

Comment: This is the only way I can see it, but it crashes Xcode every single time.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the memory debugger will only work for newer devices.  It definitely does appear on the iPhone 8 running iOS 11.  On some of my older devices it does not appear.  I'm not sure at this time what the cutoff is.